# Recommended approach to storing chat messages (node.js)

Tags: node.js, apache, laravel, socket.io

This is my first time developing a web application that requires chat functionality. There are multiple rooms and there are no restrictions as to how many people can join a room. The part that I can't get my head around is the actual approach to storing the messages. The question is more so in two parts...firstly am I correct to assume that unless all the messages are stored in a database, a newly connected user cannot retain all the previous messages? Secondly is it not recommended to save every message to the database as they are sent ? How else could I keep track if they aren't saved in real time ?

Thanks for any advice, appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store the data in memory and persist at a time interval, you can use **redis** for this. Also if all the data are required to store for future reference, you can implement scheduler like **resque** to transfer the data from redis to your db and free redis for application state data (i.e. more recent data).

Hope this will help you...

Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer....currently I'm using socket.io to handle the chatting process but the messages aren't persistent. So with Redis will I be able to cache messages and set it to commit them to persistent storage (i.e mysql database) at a specified time ?  And when new users connect I assume I can use the in memory data to retrieve the current messages ?

Comment: Yes...from redis you should come up with more recent messages i.e. within last day or just 2 days. It depends on volume of data. One Single Redis instance is capable of 4GB in-memory data...For more we have to use redis cluster...and if user wants last 7 days data etc...then you should fetch data from mysql and show it...

Answer (score 2):

Persistence is a business requirement, and yes a new user cannot see previous messages unless you have some sort of persistence storage. You can of course store messages permanently, and many apps out there do that. You can also store them temporarily and let the messages expire and be erased after a certain time period. All of this is easily accomplished using common tools such as MongoDB and Redis. If you do not need to persist messages, then you'll need to use web sockets to send messages between clients. Probably the most famous Node library for that is Socket.io